# What is the delta-v range for model rockets?

Tags: delta-v, model-rocketry

I'm curious about the delta-v of model rockets. While searching the web I found NASA's "For Educators" page [How Do Rockets Stack Up](http://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/rocketry/home/rockets_stack_up_nf.html) that was going to cover it, however the stats haven't been filled in.

Comment: "This is where the stats will go. The stats will go here." Oof. NASA's falling behind.

Comment: What would you define as a "model rocket"? And why are you interested in the delta-v? I don't think that's a very informative parameter in non-orbital applications.

Comment: Anything from [here](http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=676756011) would be considered a model rocket I guess. I'm interested in what the delta-v would be for pure curiosity. It struck me as odd that there were no clear answers on google so I though I'd ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's common for the sort of model rocket you link (e.g. Estes kit with a D-class motor) to go to approximately 1000 ft altitude.  If we assume an impulsive burn (reasonable, given that burn time << flight time) we can calculate the corresponding delta V with high school kinematics:

$$ v^2 = u^2 + 2as $$

v = final velocity = $0$ (at apogee)

u = initial velocity (to be solved)

a = acceleration due to gravity = -9.8 m/s$^2$

s = distance traveled = 1000 ft ~= 300 m

solving,
$$ u = \sqrt{2 \cdot 9.8 \cdot 300} = 77 \space m/s $$

Comment: Well, this neglects air drag, but I guess it works if you just want a rough estimate.

Comment: Isn't air drag accounted for with the approximate 1000 ft altitude?

Comment: It does indeed neglect air drag.  You could take another approach and look at the motor thrust profile, integrate that to determine total impulse and an effective specific impulse, plug that into the rocket equation along with the full and empty mass of the rocket.  But that requires several more pieces of information that one would have to determine for a particular rocket.  I took the approach in my answer for simplicity, because it only needs one input (the apogee height).

Comment: It's also possible to use the published ISP of Estes' rocket motors (which are all black powder + oxidizer) to compute the delta-v. The specific impulses range from about 80 to about 90 for Estes motors.  There's a handy "I'm too lazy to do it myself" delta-v calculator at http://www.strout.net/info/science/delta-v/   It also ignores drag. Given some *very* rough guestimates of ending weight vs starting weight, I get ~ 140 m/s delta-v.

Comment: Since it's just for curiosity ignoring drag and making a wide estimate seems reasonable. 77-140m/s will work just fine.